# Is SecureRandom thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

Is `SecureRandom` thread safe? That is, after initializing it, can access to the next random number be relied on to be thread safe? Examining the source code seems to show that it is, and [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6498354) seems to indicate that its lack of documentation as thread safe is a javadoc issue. Has anyone confirmed that it is in fact thread safe?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Yes, it is. It extends `Random`, which always had a *de facto* threadsafe implementation, and, from [Java 7, explicitly guarantees threadsafety.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

If many threads are using a single `SecureRandom`, there might be contention that hurts performance. On the other hand, initializing a `SecureRandom` instance can be relatively slow. Whether it is best to share a global RNG, or to create a new one for each thread will depend on your application. The [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class could be used as a pattern to provide a solution that supports `SecureRandom`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Oddly, the bug is marked closed as "will not fix." But they fixed it anyway. Oh well, I don't envy them the size of their bug database.

Comment: initializing a `SecureRandom` can not only be slow, but can potentially hang because of missing entropy

Comment: @WalterTross Hang? I have seen systems take 10 or 15 minutes, but I've never seen one hang. An implementation that isn't guaranteed to continue feeding its entropy pool, albeit slowly, seems like a bug in the OS.

Comment: Correct. Let's say "almost hang"... ;-)

Comment: Please keep in mind that ThreadLocalRandom is very easy to crack, so if you plan to expose generated value to the world, use SecureRandom instead http://jazzy.id.au/default/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html

Comment: @erickson - I used to have a diskless workstation running a fairly old version of Linux (probably 2.0.something) where disk interrupt times were basically the only large scale source of entropy. If you tried to grab too much random data during startup it would hang until somebody typed on the keyboard. The default script to set up the X11 "magic cookie" would take too much, and had to be rewritten to use `/dev/urandom` rather than `/dev/random`. I imagine things are a little better these days, but I would definitely not rely on being able to acquire random bits in any particular timeframe.

Comment: @Jules If seeding a `SecureRandom` blocks for a perceptible duration, your system is misconfigured. You should definitely not stop using `SecureRandom` out of some fear that it will block indefinitely.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say this answer is incorrect. The contract for Random, which guarantees thread safety, is not binding on subclasses. Certainly all the other properties of Random documented are not binding on subclasses, so I don't see why thread-safety should be assumed.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Failure to preserve a property of the supertype would violate the substitutability principle.

Comment: This answer is incorrrect. Thread safety is not garantee if a sub-class override the method. The oviridden method must respect the same thread safety contract as the parent (otherwise it's a mess) but there is no garantee. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545604/how-to-ensure-thread-safety-of-subclass-methods-from-a-superclass and https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM00-J.+Do+not+override+thread-safe+methods+with+methods+that+are+not+thread-safe.

Comment: @Algiz That’s true, any code could have a bug that makes it malfunction. But, “no class is thread-safe, because you can’t guarantee there are no bugs” isn’t a useful answer. Until I find a widely-used `SecureRandom` implementation that’s not thread-safe, I believe this answer is correct for any practical situation.

Comment: @erickson I believe SecureRandom is thread safe but it is not due to what you explain. The answer from Matt Quail give a more strong background.

Comment: At least in JDK 10, SecureRandom is based on a provider and checks if the provider is thread safe, synchronizing if it's not, in nextBytes. So while it's possible for a subclass to override that behavior, it would be foolish, and alternative algorithms should be providers not subclasses anyway.

Comment: It's interesting that over time the SecureRandom implementation has more carefully taken care to be threadsafe. In Java 7 the appropriate methods are `synchronized`. In Java 8 they are not. By Java 10 they are thread-safe again and the javadocs explicitly describe how they achieve this and what service providers need to do to announce their thread safety.

Answer (score 13):

The current implementation of `SecureRandom` is thread safe, specifically the two mutating methods `nextBytes(bytes[])` and `setSeed(byte[])` are synchronized.

Well, as far as I've been able to tell, all mutating methods are eventually routed through those two methods, and `SecureRandom` overrides a few methods in `Random` to ensure that. Which works but could be brittle if the implementation is changed in the future.

The best solution is to manually synchronize on the `SecureRandom` instance first. This means each call stack will acquire two locks on the same object, but that is usually very cheap on modern JVMs. That is, there is not much harm in explicitly synchronizing yourself. For example:

```
    SecureRandom rnd = ...;

    byte[] b = new byte[NRANDOM_BYTES];
    synchronized (rnd) {
        rnd.nextBytes(b);
    }
```

Comment: At least in JDK 10, SecureRandom is based on a provider and checks if the provider is thread safe, only synchronizing if it's not, in nextBytes.

Comment: `java.security.SecureRandom#nextBytes` in Java 8 is not synchronized. Could you please specify in what Java version did you find a synchronized `#nextBytes`?.

Answer (score 5):

Please see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165115 which was fixed in Java 9.

It says:

> `SecureRandom` objects are safe for use by multiple concurrent
> threads. A `SecureRandom` service provider can advertise that it is
> thread-safe by setting the service provider attribute "ThreadSafe" to
> "true" when registering the provider. Otherwise, the `SecureRandom`
> class will synchronize access to the following `SecureRandomSpi`
> methods: `SecureRandomSpi.engineSetSeed(byte[])`,
> `SecureRandomSpi.engineNextBytes(byte[])`,
> `SecureRandomSpi.engineNextBytes(byte[], SecureRandomParameters)`,
> `SecureRandomSpi.engineGenerateSeed(int)`, and
> `SecureRandomSpi.engineReseed(SecureRandomParameters)`.

Comment: Thank you for the much needed >10 year update!