# SecureRandom in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, random, hash

Is there a `SecureRandom.hex()`-like (ruby) function in JavaScript which generates a random hash for me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is SecureRandom thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461568/is-securerandom-thread-safe)

Comment: @PalakMistry the question from your comment is about Java, not JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such helper function in JS. You can generates a fairly random hash using:

```
function hex(n){
 n = n || 16;
 var result = '';
 while (n--){
  result += Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
 }
 return result;
}
```

You can modify it to form a guid:

```
function generateGuid(){
 var result = '', n=0;
 while (n<32){
  result += (~[8,12,16,20].indexOf(n++) ? '-': '') +    
            Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
 }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was led to this question as a top search engine result using the following keywords:

- securerandom range js
- securerandom js

As such, I thought it would be good to update this post with a working answer available today (2019):

The snippet below employs [`Crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) for sourcing random values said to be,

> ... cryptographically strong ... using a pseudo-random number generator seeded with a value with enough entropy ... suitable for cryptographic usages.

Thus, we have:

```js
var N = 32;
var rng = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
var rawBytes = Array
              .from(rng.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(N)))
              .map(c => String.fromCharCode(c))
              .join([]);
```

Now, below is a fun little hex-encoder I cooked up as a one-liner using some `Array` functions for looping:

```js
function hexEncode(s) {
  return s.split('').map(c => (c < String.fromCharCode(16) ? '0' : '') + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).join([]);
}
```

Finally, if you want to combine the two above for generating random hashes, you can just swap out and adapt the `.map()` function accordingly and package it up like so:

```js
function secureRandomHash(N) {
  N = N || 32; // Coalesce if size parameter N is left undefined

  // TODO: Consider refactoring with lazy-loaded function
  // to set preferred RNG provider, else throw an error here
  // to generate noise that no secure RNG is available for
  // this application.
  var rng = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;

  return Array
           .from(rng.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(N)))
           .map(c => (c < 16 ? '0' : '') + c.toString(16)).join([]);
}
```

Happy coding!

**Edit:** Turns out I ended up needing this in my own project which also implements the suggested TODO in the previous example (lazy-loading) so here we go:

```js
Math.secureRandom = function() {
  var rng = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
  if (rng === undefined)
    throw 'No suitable RNG found';

  // Lazy-load this if- branch
  Math.secureRandom = function() {
    // More secure implementation of Math.random (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues#Examples)
    return rng.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967296;
  };

  return Math.secureRandom();
}
```

Or if you're feeling really adventurous...

```js
// Auto-upgrade Math.random with a more secure implementation only if crypto is available
(function() {
  var rng = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
  if (rng === undefined)
    return;

  // Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues#Examples
  Math.random = function() {
    return rng.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967296;
  };
})();

console.log(Math.random());
```

Whether extending `Math` or overwriting `Math.random()` for a drop-in replacement is appropriate for your application or target audience is left purely as an academic exercise to the implementor. Be sure to check with your architect first! License MIT here of course :)

Comment: If the random value is between 0x0 - 0xF your conversion to hex skips the leading zero. To add the leading zero to those 8 but values, you can use `.map(c => (c < 16 ? '0':'') + c.toString(16)).join('')`

Comment: @some Yes, you're totally right. I meant to come back to that but got distracted chasing down something else. Will update my answer shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Answer has been updated, along with what should be the equivalent in the 
`hexEncode` helper.

Comment: By the way, [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)  returns a number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1), but `crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967295` will return a value in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0 AND 1). Change the value to 4294967296 (2^32) to exclude 1.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/2510) to update the example in the documentation on mozilla.org.

Comment: @some [corrected] Just finished updating that page; turns out it's just another Wiki page and I'm not sure exactly how I feel about that sudden reality :)

Comment: Hmm... Looked at the [revision history](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues$history) and that scared me... `window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 1e+10`, `return window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] // 4294967295;`