# Static token generation?

Tags: java, static, secure-random

I have found this question [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string) and the answer contains this code:

```
public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }
}
```

And my question is can I make `nextSessionId` `static`?

I know that technically I can, but I am curious if it was intentionally made non-static. I know that probably author won't read my question and he won't explain to me what he had is his mind responding to this question, but maybe there is something I don't know and someone can explain me what reasoning could be behind this answer. I think that there is no point in making this method non-static, because I get nothing from creating `SessionIdentifierGenerator` object. I'd prefer calling nextSessionId without creating `SessionIdentifierGenerator` object.

Comment: You'd have to make `random` static as well

Comment: @Jonk Yes, but I don't see problem with that. Is it bad?

Comment: No, it's just an observation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, technically, you can make the method `static`. 
The class is `final` anyway and doesn't `extend` any other class, so the argument of overriding the method wouldn't count here.

As [JonK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3419894/jonk) mentioned in comments, the `random` field must be made static as well. 
Because [`SecureRandom` is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461568/is-securerandom-thread-safe), this is not a problem either.

One problem with a static method is that it would be *harder* to mock from within tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make it `static` if you want. But why should you?

you may want to read the following then reconsider making things `static`:

1. [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)
2. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-having-a-static-method-in-Java
3. http://devsolvd.com/questions/java-when-to-use-static-methods