# Is BouncyCastle's SecureRandom in C# threadsafe?

Tags: c#, random, cryptography, bouncycastle

The answer is apparently [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461624/1709587) for the implementation in Java, but how about `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom` in C#?

Comment: Related (since it's also about the undocumented basics of how to use this class correctly): https://stackoverflow.com/q/46792373/1709587

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, as far as I know, there is no official (or even any) documentation of C# Bouncy Castle port - all we can do is look at source code and try to draw some conclusions. Here is source code of [SecureRandom](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/security/SecureRandom.cs). We can see that the main methods there are `NextCounterValue` (used to generate seeds) and `NextBytes` used to generate actual random data. `NextCounterValue` is thread-safe (uses `Interlocked.Increment`). `NextBytes` forwards implementation to instance of `IRandomGenerator`. Since you can pass any instance of `IRandomGenerator` to constructor of `SecureRandom` - we can conclude that its thread safety depends on that of `IRandomGenerator` used.

Also when on full .NET Framework, `SecureRandom` uses [CryptoApiRandomGenerator](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/prng/CryptoApiRandomGenerator.cs) as master generator (to generate seeds) and that one is just wrapper around .NET `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` which as we know is thread safe.

What if you just create `SecureRandom` without passing any `IRandomGenerator`? Then it will create instance of `DigestRandomGenerator` ([code](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/prng/DigestRandomGenerator.cs)) which seems to be thread-safe (uses simple `lock` in `NextBytes`).

All in all we can say that `SecureRandom` is thread safe if you are not passing an instance of `IRandomGenerator` which is not thread-safe to it.